# Word 2016 breaks words with superscript symbols from the "phonetic extensions" unicode block

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using superscript letters from the "phonetic extensions" unicode block (U+1d2c through U+1d61) in scholarly transliteration in a Word 2016 document. Unfortunately, Word keeps treating these symbols as if they were punctuation, breaking the word and completely defeating the purpose of that segment of the unicode. It does not do this with other non-superscript parts of that unicode block nor with superscript symbols from other blocks (such as anything from the "Superscripts and Subscripts" block or U+02B0 through U+02C1 of the "Spacing Modifier Letters" block).

For instance, the word *ˀĒͅyᵊṯānᵊ* is treated as if it is two words *ˀĒͅy* and *ṯān* and the two *ᵊ* symbols function as if they were punctuation. It's as if I wrote the word as *ˀĒͅy,ṯān,* (with commas instead of *ᵊ*). I cannot select the whole word through double clicking it nor will it be treated as a single word in spellcheck.

How do I fix this? This has been a massive waste of my time, as I cannot spellcheck academic documents (even if I add words to the dictionary) unless I go through them by hand.

Thanks!

Comment: How important is it that you use those specific codepoints? If it isn't essential, just as an experiment, instead of U+1D4A Modifier Letter Small Schwa, I used U+0259 Latin Small Letter Schwa and superscripted it. It looks almost the same in the font I used (you could adjust the superscript height) and you end up with a single word. instead of 4 words. What I don't know is whether there are suitable equicvalents for the other codepoints that you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very important, simply because I need to be able to maintain the superscripted nature of those characters across multiple platforms and copy/pasting is an essential part of my process (for instance, I'd like to prevent myself from using the ```<sup>``` tag every time I need superscript in html since it adds 11 characters that I have to type every single time I use an ultrashort vowel).MS Word is the only program I use that exhibits this behavior with these characters.

Comment: Understood. FWIW I can't think of any setting or other approach that would fix this. Perhaps worth clicking Word's smile/frown feedback feature and sending off a message to the developers, but I would be very surprised if that had any effect.

Comment: Thanks. It's such an odd thing. Like I'm not sure why they would have it behave in such a manner, especially when no other superscript symbols in other blocks or other symbols within the same block (including subscript) do this.

Comment: Not that it helps you in any way, but from a coding perspective there are two ways Microsoft could approach "character classification," in this case "which characters cause word breaks". They could either go by Unicode Range, i.e. "we've decided that codepoints from U+A to U+B will break words", or they could look up relevant character attributes in the Unicode character database and decide what to do based on those. If the latter, either there is something unexected in the character database in that area that causes the behaviour, or perhaps the character database was wrong at some point...

Comment: ...if the former, it just looks as if they made a mistake.